# Phython getting issue with urls path

Tags: python, django-templates, django-urls

I'm learning pyhton django, and I created a file `nosotros.html` inside of `templates/paginas`:

[image]

and on `views.py` my I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def inicio(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1> Bienvenido </h1>")
def nosotros(request):
    return render(request, "paginas/nosotros.html")
def libros(request):
    return render(request, "libros/index.html")
```

and on my `urls.py`  I have:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.inicio, name="inicio"),
    path('nosotros', views.nosotros, name="nosotros"),
    path('libros', views.libros, name="libros"),
]
```

so if I try to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/nosotros` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/libros` I got `TemplateDoesNotExist at /libros` or `TemplateDoesNotExist at /nosotros`

what's wrong??? or what I'm doing wrong?

the `setting.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

this file `setting.py` is on CRUDMySQL, currently I never write or updated, so it's intact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the path to your template directory in the `DIRS` list:

```
LIBRERIA_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'libreria'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ LIBRERIA_DIR / 'templates' ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I'm confused about the structure of your project folder, since you have your `settings.py` in the base directory of your project. The actual path you need to use might be different than the one I provided.

Just make sure the directory you put in `DIRS` is the *absolute* path to your template folder.

Comment: yes, it worked, definitely adding  `LIBRERIA_DIR / 'templates'` solved my issue, sorry about the structure, just I'm learning python django, thanks you so much